# QThreadPool maxThreadCount different in Application and DLL

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, dll, threadpool

When using QThreadPool::globalInstance() in an application I can set the maximum number of threads to a number (say 50 for this example)

```
QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(50);
```

Which later we can query within that same application and 50 will be returned. However, if QThreadPool::maxThreadCount() is queried from within a DLL called by that same application, it returns that the maximum thread count is only 12. I can then increase the maxThreadCount in the library to be any number I would like, separate from the applications maxThreadCount number.

So is the QThreadPool::globalInstance only global to the independent application and libraries somehow? Why wouldn't a Qt DLL and application that share the same process not have the same global QThreadPool?

Comment: That implies two separate instances of thread pool I guess. It is likely because of static variable with thread count being allocated for both EXE and DLL. The question is then how the project was linked altogether in the first place? Is there a way to make sure we have one thread pool object in the app?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the implementation of QThreadPool https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qglobalstatic.h.html#158
we can see that :

```
QThreadPool *QThreadPool::globalInstance()
    {
        return theInstance();
    }
```

which is defined here https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/thread/qthreadpool.cpp.html#50

```
 Q_GLOBAL_STATIC(QThreadPool, theInstance)
```

From here, if for some obscure reason your dll and your exec are not linked with the exact same Qt core dll, you would get the problem